# Java Serialization Deserialization from HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, serialization, hdfs, deserialization

I am creating a serialized treemap locally and transferring it to a HDFS directory on Hadoop 2.7.3 as below.

```
  // Create tree map and seralize to local folder
  String localPath = "/home/test/file"
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(localPath);
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
  oos.writeObject(treemap);
  oos.close();
  fos.close();

  // Transfer serialzied file to HDFS 
  Path hdfsPath = new Path("hdfs://localhost:54310/user/filename");
  FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf);
  InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(localPath));
  OutputStream out = fs.create(hdfsPath);
  IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, 4096, true);

  // delete local copy
  File f = new File(localPath);
  f.delete();
```

The size of the serialized file is 17 MB. And then I re-read the serialized file and deserialize it at a later point.

```
 String filename = "hdfs://localhost:54310/user/filename"
 FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(uri, conf);
 InputStream in = fs.open(new Path(filename));
 ObjectInputStream objReader = new ObjectInputStream(in);
 map = (TreeMap) objReader.readObject();
```

This deserialize operation by itself is taking 40 seconds, while the remaining parts of the program runs in 4-6 seconds. I tried running the deserialization locally instead of on a HDFS file and it finishes in a few seconds. Any idea why it would take so long in HDFS?

Comment: From looking at your code, I don't see anything glaring. I would suggest profiling or reading the hdfs file into a temporary byte array so you can time the read operation vs deserialization. What's your hdfs block size? I imagine the file is all in a single block.